# Access another device's Windows Service

Tags: tcp, windows-services

I have created a Windows Service that is located on the address:

```
tcp://127.0.0.1:555
```

On my Local machine.
And I have a program that connects to this service in order to do some jobs.
What I am wondering is, is it possible to connect to the same Windows service while it is located on another device?
Simply put, can I access a service that is located on another machine?

Comment: Yes, via some communication method such as WCF.  That doesn't seem like much of a question, however.  You already have the `tcp` tag, so you kinda know what you need to do.

Comment: @Will Could you please be a bit more specific? I'm not sure I can follow.

Comment: Nope.  You don't have near enough info in here for me to speculate.  I don't know how you're currently connecting (named pipes? looks like TCP, but via what technology? NET remoting?  web service?).  If you're already connected to the service via TCP on the same machine, then make sure the firewall is open and you can connect from anywhere on the local network.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to starting or stopping services from a remote machine? If then you can use the below command line.

```
NET USE \\computername\IPC$ /U:domainname\username password
SC \\computername START service
```

Comment: No I don't need to start or stop a service, I just to tell my program about the exact location of this service via a `tcp` address. So that it does not look in the services on its own local device but on the other computer's services.